# Подсчитать итоговые суммы для полей в Oracle

Tags: oracle

Есть запрос

```
select
    tmp.user,
    tmp.sars,
    tmp.nosars,
    tmp.itogo
from (
    ***
) tmp
```

Вместо *** сложная логика, но в итоге запрос выводит указанные поля. Нужно для каждого из полей `tmp.sars, tmp.nosars, tmp.itogo` в конце подсчитать итоговую сумму, а под полем `tmp.user` написать Итого:. Как такое сделать?

В итоге хотелось бы получить следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте ROLLUP.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test ("user" NCHAR(5), sars INT, nosars INT, itogo INT);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test
>     SELECT 'user1', 10, 20, 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>     SELECT 'user2', 20, 30, 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>     SELECT 'user3', 30, 40, 70 FROM DUAL;
> ```

> ```
> select
>     COALESCE(tmp."user", N'Итого:') "user",
>     SUM(tmp.sars) sars,
>     SUM(tmp.nosars) nosars,
>     SUM(tmp.itogo) itogo
> from (SELECT * FROM test) tmp
> GROUP BY ROLLUP(tmp."user");
> ```
>
> | user | SARS | NOSARS | ITOGO |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | user1 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
> | user2 | 20 | 30 | 50 |
> | user3 | 30 | 40 | 70 |
> | Итого: | 60 | 90 | 150 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=69b8139d14d0275d8ec8ca4cfc6b5add)*

Comment: Спасибо большое. Только можете подсказать. как тут работает COALESCE?

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна ROLLUP добавляет итоговую строку (или строки), причём значение в полях GROUPING SET текущей записи значения - NULL. COALESCE по этому NULL определяет, что строка - итоговая, заменяя этот NULL на соотв. значение. Уберите COALESCE и сравните выводы запросов.

Comment: Да, поняла спасибо. Я пыталась использовать grouping sets, grouping, а оказывается все намного легче)